# "In dieser Weise", "auf diese Weise" - Warum die unterschiedlichen Kasus?

Tags: grammatical-case

> in dieser Weise
> auf diese Weise

Ich interessiere mich, warum man den Akkusativ mit der Proposition "auf" in "auf diese Weise" benutzt, wobei tatsächlich der Dativ mit "in" benutzt wird. Gibt es da eine logische Erklärung dafür?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meiner Ansicht nach gibt es keine logische Erklärung, warum "in" und "auf" bei dieser Bedeutung mit unterschiedlichem Kasus verwendet werden.

Sowohl "in" als auch "auf" können bei einer räumlichen Bedeutung sowohl mit Akkusativ (wohin?) als auch mit Dativ (wo?) benutzt werden.

Bei nicht-räumlicher Bedeutung ist die Verwendung unterschiedlich.

Zitat (auszugsweise) von https://blog.leo.org/2012/04/27/in-dieser-weise-und-auf-diese-weise/

> Nach *auf* steht bei einer nicht räumlichen Verwendung meistens der Akkusativ (*auf keinen Fall*, *auf den Cent genau*; siehe hier(*)). Dies gilt auch für *auf eine bestimmte Weise*.

> Nach *in* steht bei nicht räumlicher und nicht zeitlicher Verwendung der Akkusativ, wenn die Bedeutung „dynamisch“ ist (*ins Gespräch kommen*, *in einen Frosch verwandeln*), und der Dativ, wenn die Bedeutung „statisch“ ist (*im Gespräch sein*, *im Notfall*; siehe hier(*)). In übertragenem Sinne tut man etwas nicht *in eine bestimmte Weise hinein*, sondern *innerhalb einer bestimmten Weise*. Deshalb sagt man *in einer bestimmen Weise*.

> Bei der Wechselpräposition *in* hat der Unterschied zwischen statisch und dynamisch also bei nicht räumlicher Verwendung einen größeren Einfluss auf die Wahl des Falles als bei *auf*.

(*) Die Links beim Wort "hier" auf der Originalseite funktionieren nicht mehr. Deshalb habe ich diese Links nicht übernommen.

Answer (score 2):

Die früheren deutschen Dialekte unterschieden sich stark nicht nur in ihrer Aussprache und ihrem Wortschatz, sondern auch in ihrer Grammatik. So wurden auch manche Präpositionen in den verschiedenen Dialekten unterschiedlich verwendet. Heute haben sich durch die Verbreitung und angleichende Wirkung der Hochsprache viele Unterschiede zwischen den Dialekten verloren, oder umgekehrt haben, wo Dialekte sich unterschieden, beide Varianten Eingang ins Hochdeutsche gefunden, wo sie nun als synonyme Formen existieren.

Schaut man sich die [regionale Verbreitung](http://mediawiki.ids-mannheim.de/VarGra/index.php/Auf_eine_/_in_einer_Weise) der beiden Formen "auf eine Weise" und "in einer Weise" an, dann kann man vielleicht noch Spuren einstmaliger Dialektunterschiede erkennen. "In einer Weise" scheint vor allem im Westen Österreichs und in Lichtenstein gebräuchlich(er) gewesen zu sein, während "auf eine Weise" im übrigen deutschen Sprachraum häufiger verwendet wird. Man kann also vermuten, dass die Wendung "in einer Weise" ursprünglich im Kontaktgebiet von Bodenseealemannisch und Oberbairisch verbreitet war.

---

Schaut man sich die [Präpositionalgruppen](https://www.dwds.de/wp/Weise) an, in denen "Weise" am häufigsten vorkommt, dann fällt auf, dass die meisten Verben in Verbindung mit "auf ... Weise" verwendet werden und jeweils nur wenige Verben mit "in ... Weise" oder mit beiden Präpositionen gleich häufig.

*Verben, die überwiegend mit "auf ... Weise" verwendet werden*

`ausdrücken, bekommen, beschreiben, bestätigen, bleiben, bringen, demonstrieren, entstehen, entziehen, erfahren, erhalten, erreichen, erzählen, erzeugen, finden, gelangen, gelingen, gewinnen, helfen, herstellen, hoffen, interpretieren, kommen, lernen, nähern, retten, schaffen, scheinen, schützen, sichern, sicherstellen, sparen, stärken, töten, umbringen, umgehen, verdienen, verhindern, verknüpfen, verkörpern, verlieren, vermeiden, vermitteln, verschaffen, verschwinden, verstehen, versuchen`

*Verben, die überwiegend mit "in ... Weise" verwendet werden*

`ändern, äußern, beeinträchtigen, berühren, beteiligen, betreffen, entsprechen, erfolgen, ergänzen, fühlen, gelten, verhalten, verletzen`

*Verben, die gleichermaßen mit "in ... Weise" und "auf ... Weise" verwendet werden*

`beeinflussen, behandeln, beitragen, darstellen, entwickeln, erfüllen, fördern, geschehen, lassen, lösen, machen, nutzen, reagieren, tun, unterstützen, verändern, verbinden, wirken, zeigen`

Ob dieser Verteilung ein System zugrundeliegt, kann ich nicht erkennen. Eventuell ist in der Gruppe der Verben mit "auf ... Weise" häufiger ein Gegenstand das Objekt ("etwas auf eine Weise herstellen"), in der Gruppe der Verben mit "in ... Weise" häufiger eine Person ("jemanden in einer Weise berühren"), aber hierzu gibt es zu viele Ausnahmen. Falls es eine Regelmäßigkeit der Verteilung gibt, sind es möglicherweise mehrere Regeln, die hier miteinander wirken.

Tatsächlich jedenfalls empfinde ich bei manchen Verben die eine Verbindung als "wohlklingender", "richtiger" oder vielleicht auch nur vertrauter als die andere.

---

Der einzige echte Unterschied scheint mir zu sein, dass man üblicherweise "in keinster Weise" *(= ganz und gar nicht)*, nicht "auf keinste Weise" sagt (obwohl sich natürlich auch für letzteres Belege im Internet finden lassen, jedoch in weitaus kleinerer Zahl – 4260 : 1600000).

Comment: Kann man also überhaupt sagen, dass 'etwas auf einer Weise tun' eindeutig falsch ist?